# multiple search key for binary search tree in linux C

Tags: c, algorithm, search

I define a binary tree as a search table. The tree is a linked list binary tree, the node is like

```
typedef struct node{
    int key;
    char *buf;
    ...
}node_t;
```

typedef table_t node_t *;
so I have functions like

```
  insert(table_t table, node_t node)
  search(table_t table, node_t node)
```

now I have multiple keys, like

```
typedef struct node{
    int key1;
    int key2;
    char *buf;
    ...
}node_t;
```

and I want to have functions like:

```
  search_by_key1(table_t table, node_t node, int key1)
  search_by_key2(table_t table, node_t node, int key2)
```

indeed, it is  like a database, I can search any keys for an item.

are there any source code examples? I'm using linux C
thanks!

Comment: Withg multiple keys, don't you need multiple trees? Else, which key determines which node is on the left and which on the right?

Comment: yes, I think maybe I need to make two trees if I have two keys, are there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

A binary-tree can only be indexed by a single key.

If you want to index using multiple keys, you can build a meta-tree for every key, meta-tree have meta-node(s) where:

```
typedef struct meta_node
{
    int index;
    node * data;

    ...
}
meta_node_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a binary tree, key's only make sense in relation to each-other. Meaning that key1_a makes sense in the left branch only if key1_b is larger/smaller in the right branch (depending how you structure it). If you had a tree of two set of keys, hypothetically they could be in the same tree data-structure if they had the same proportions. As in, if each key in key2 was exactly 50 above key1. But that wouldn't really be useful at all.

The only idea I have is making it so there are some null value keys. So that if you're traversing your tree and you're at a leaf of key1 but not key2, you just keep going, and the rest of the tree lower down will have a null value (maybe -1?) in the key, or will have a boolean trigger making it so key1 is no longer present in this branch of the tree. It's kind of hard to describe, but do you see what I mean? Like basically treat it almost as 2 inter-weaved trees, and go along together until you have to diverge (and do that while keeping the actual tree structure the same, but have null values for one of the keys)

It sounds overly complex though, so I don't know if it'd be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two trees, but still use the same nodes:

```
struct basic_node {
    int key;
    struct basic_node *left, *right;
    struct node *node;
};
struct node {
    struct basic_node tree1;
    struct basic_node tree2;
    char *data;
};

struct node *tree1_root, *tree2_root;
```

When you create a node, you'll allocate a `struct node`, then insert each `basic_node` separately to the respective tree, according to its key. In each `basic_node`, set the `node` pointer to the node containing it.

When looking up, just start with either tree root, and do a simple lookup, which would lead you to the desired `basic_node`, and then to the node itself.

If you want to delete, you'll have to first unlink the node from both trees, then you can free it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I came across it in searching for the exact data structure that the user is looking for...

Long story short, it *is* possible to have a binary search tree with multiple keys, called a K-D tree.

Basically, what you do is construct a normal binary search tree, but you keep track of how "deep" within the tree the node is. For two keys like this question uses, All nodes with depth that are even have their children sorted based on the value of key_a, and all nodes with a depth that are odd have their children sorted based on value of key_b.

Similarly, when you search the tree you iterate down the branches. When you are on a node of even depth, you decide which branch to go down based on whether the value stored in key_a of that node is less than or greater than the desired value of key_a. When you are on a node of odd depth, you decide based on the node's value and the desired value of key_b.

If I recall correctly, google uses a very similar data structure to quickly find locations based on a range from a geographical position, using latitude as one key and longitude as the other.